# Module not found: Error: Package path ./index is not exported from package node_modules/rxjs (see exports field in /node_modules/rxjs/package.json)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular12, rxjs7

I am trying `RxJs7` in my angular 12.2.0 project and it seems like the path of rxjs operator and method changed.

I am getting the below error

```
./dist/candypal/website/fesm2015/candypal-website.js:8:0-50 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./index is not exported from package /Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/candypal/node_modules/rxjs (see exports field in /Users/aniruddh/aniruddh/develop/experiment/candypal/node_modules/rxjs/package.json)
```

Note that the above error is coming from a library that uses rxjs7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your code, replace

```
import { Whatever } from 'rxjs/index'
```

by

```
import { Whatever } from 'rxjs'
```

The rxjs/index folder was removed from rxjs.